# Promise and access to access=private attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service, promises

I am trying to use `Promise` to make my code more readable and efficient but I'm stuck with the inability to get/set private attribute values.
Consider the following example:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" access="private" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

The `doInit` logic:

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp, event, helper) {

        Promise.resolve(1)
            .then(function(message) {
                cmp.set("v.message", message);
                console.log(cmp.get("v.message"));
        });
```

I am unable to set or get a value for the `message` attribute.
**However**, if I remove the `access="private"` property the code works.

I found a similar question [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148478/promise-returns-a-locked-object-inside-lightning-component-when-locker-service-i) but according to the answer - if locker service was the problem - it should have been fixed already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answer my own question. I forgot to use `$A.getCallback()` [to grant the correct access level to the asynchronous code](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_get_callback.htm).

The code should be:

```
Promise.resolve(1)
    .then($A.getCallback(function(message) {
        cmp.set("v.message", message);
        console.log(cmp.get("v.message"));
}));
```

Comment: Your post just saved me from removing `access="private"` from a bunch of components. Thanks!

Comment: damn, I really need to remember putting that in my promises :D Think this is the 4th time that your post solves my problem