# How to make code which uses Lightning promises look more synchronous

Tags: lightning, promises

When I read about [promises](http://nebulaconsulting.co.uk/using-javascript-promises-to-chain-asynchronous-actions-in-salesforce-lightning/), I see that they should appear as solution to prevent [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) and [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)) but when I actually try to write a code which would use Lightning promises it still doesn't look like synchronous code, it still resembles both pyramid of doom and callback hell.

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        $A.getCallback(function(record) {
            return helper.promise2(component, helper, record).then(
                $A.getCallback(function(){
                    console.log("Success");
                    helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
                }), 
                $A.getCallback(function(errorMessage){
                    console.log("Rejected by second promise2");
                    helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage);
                })

            )
        }),

        $A.getCallback(function(errors){
            console.log("Rejected by first promise1");
            let message = errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0 ? errors[0].message :'Unknown error';
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + message);
        })

    )
}
```

Is that possible to refactor this code to look more like synchronous code and without callback hell or pyramid of doom?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read this: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: See Aidan Harding's solution at
[helperFunctionAsPromise](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204487/how-to-make-code-which-uses-lightning-promises-look-more-synchronous)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have two basic problems. First, you don't need $A.getCallback unless you need to call component.set. At all other points, it's superfluous.

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        function(record) {
            return helper.promise2(component, helper, record).then(
                function(){
                    console.log("Success");
                    helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
                }, 
                function(errorMessage){
                    console.log("Rejected by second promise2");
                    helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage);
                }
            )
        },
        function(errors){
            console.log("Rejected by first promise1");
            let message = errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0 ? errors[0].message :'Unknown error';
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + message);
        }
    )
}
```

---

Next, you typically chain a then from the previous then:

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        function(record) {
            return helper.promise2(component, helper, record);
        },
        function(errors){
            console.log("Rejected by first promise1");
            let message = errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0 ? errors[0].message :'Unknown error';
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + message);
        }
    ).then(
        function(){
            console.log("Success");
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
        }, 
        function(errorMessage){
            console.log("Rejected by second promise2");
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage);
        }
    )
}
```

---

Also, you typically want to use catch instead of the two-parameter then version, which lets you have as single error handler:

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        function(record) {
            return helper.promise2(component, helper, record);
        }
    ).then(
        function(){
            console.log("Success");
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
        }
    ).catch(
        function(errorMessage){
            console.log("Error occuring during chain");
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage);
        }
    );
}
```

---

As a bonus, arrow functions makes things a bit more legible:

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        record => helper.promise2(component, helper, record);
    ).then(
        () => {
            console.log("Success");
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
        }
    ).catch(
        (errorMessage) => {
            console.log("Error occuring during chain");
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage);
        }
    );
}
```

---

After that, you might want to remove the debug logs for production use:

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        record => helper.promise2(component, helper, record)
    ).then(
        () => helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
    ).catch(
        errorMessage => helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage)
    );
}
```

This is what you'd typically see in production-ready code (plus comments, as necessary).

Comment: Is that possible to use `arrow functions` in Lightning?

Comment: @Patlatus Yes, you can use arrow functions in Lightning.

Comment: @sfdcfox how are you using arrow functions, I have not seen them work in Lightning?

Comment: @MikeHavrilla You can't use arrow functions for controller/helper methods, but you can use them as callbacks, which I tend to do because they're incredibly handy.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I have found some possible solution to beautify this code.

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        $A.getCallback(helper.promise2),

        $A.getCallback(function(errors){
            console.log("Rejected by first promise1");
            let message = errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0 ? errors[0].message :'Unknown error';
            helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + message);
        })

    ).then(
                $A.getCallback(function(){
                    console.log("Success");
                    helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
                }), 
                $A.getCallback(function(errorMessage){
                    console.log("Rejected by second promise2");
                    helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage);
                })

    )
}
```

However, if we need `component` and `helper` variables in the second promise then we have to tweak `resolve` statement and change it from

```
resolve(record)
```

to

```
resolve({'c':component, 'h':helper, 'r':record})
```

and to tweak the second promise from

```
sendMessagePromise : function(component, helper, record) {
    ...
```

to

```
sendMessagePromise : function(value) {
    let component = value.c, helper = value.h, record = value.r;
```

---

Also using suggestions from sfdcfox I could rewrite this as following:

```
main: function(component, helper) {
    helper.promise1(component, helper).then(
        promise2
    ).then(
        () => helper.showToastMessage(component, "Great Success!!!!")
    ).catch(
        errorMessage => helper.showToastMessage(component, "Failure " + errorMessage)
    );
}
```