# How to use Promises to kick off one helper method after another one is completed?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, promises

I've got these two helper methods:

```
submitBookingInformation: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.createLead(component, event, helper);
    helper.saveRecord(component, event, helper);
}
```

helper.createLead simply creates a lead with Lightning Data Service (no server-side apex to create the lead)
helper.createLead needs to finish first, otherwise helper.saveRecord will give an error since it's expecting a record ID (from that lead) just created. Can I somehow use Promises here to kick off "helper.saveRecord" once helper.createLead successfully finished?

These two helper methods are on one button.

Thanks a lot!

```
<force:recordData aura:id="accountRecordCreator"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.newAccount}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleNewAccount}"
                  targetError="{!v.newAccountError}" />
```

creating the lead:

```
({
    saveBaseAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("accountRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                // record is saved successfully
                var customerAccountId = saveResult.recordId; // Gets the record ID of the account created
                var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:CustomerSubmitForm");
                        appEvent.setParams({
                            customerAccountId: customerAccountId // customerAccountId in the CustomerSubmitForm event is now set to the ID that was just created
                        });
                appEvent.fire(); // Fires the event to store customerAccountId in the Event "CustomerSubmitForm.evt"
                console.log(customerAccountId);
                var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");

                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Saved",
                    "message": "The record was saved."
                });
                resultsToast.fire();
            }
            else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // handle the incomplete state
                console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
            }
            else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                // handle the error state
                console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                resultToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Error",
                    "message": "Please complete the form"
                })
                resultsToast.fire();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Loading the appointment record

```
({
    saveRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
        var event = $A.get("event.force:createRecord");

                if (event) {
                    event.setParams({
                        entityApiName: "Sales_Appointment__c",
                        defaultFieldValues: {
                            Resource__c: component.get("v.resourceId"),
                            Dealership__c: component.get("v.accountId"),
                            Lead__c: component.get("v.customerAccountId"),

                        }
                    })
                    event.fire();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Not available")
                }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 4):

That would look like this:

```
 new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
   helper.createLead(component, event, helper, resolve, reject))
 .then(value =>
   helper.saveRecord(component, event, helper, value)
 );
```

You'll need to modify createLead to accept the resolve and reject callbacks, and when the initial process is done in createLead, you call `resolve(record.Id)` or some such, which will be the value passed to the `then` value.

Also see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/204489) for an additional demonstration.

Comment: Not really sure how this is done. I'm creating the lead using Lightning Data Service.. should I wrap that in a callback? It's using 
`component.find("accountRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) ....{`

Comment: @erikvm Does [this help](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_data_service/units/lightning_data_service_manipulate_records)? You don't normally need  Promises for your use case, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am using force:recordData to create a lead
I think I do need to use async call / promises (please correct me if I'm wrong). I've got a custom lightning page with a "Submit appointment" button. For the "Submit appointment" button to be saved, there's needs to be a Lead record on that appointment. The lead comes from a form that the person fills out. However, I want to have the lead created and the appointment record saved on the same button. 

I could simply have a "Save Lead" button that stores that record ID and then populates the sales appointment field, but I want it all in one button.

Comment: Basically, my `helper.createLead` is using force:recordData to create a lead, and the `helper.saveRecord` is displaying a new sales appointment record (a popup) with `<lightning:recordViewForm ...  /> `

Comment: @erikvm Yeah, you don't need a Promise for this; you can display the sales appointment record in createLead's callback function.

Comment: I updated my post with how I create the lead and how I then create the new record for my appointment record. Any chance you can help me out on how to fix it, honestly not sure. (Variables are currently called account but I'm referring to lead)

Appreciate it.

Comment: @sfdx I am putting the saveRecord inside the "if saveResult === SUCCESS" without any success.. any chance I can ask you in the chat?

Comment: @erikvm Yes, if you need to, we can chat. Off the top of my head, it looks like you're not seeing the toast because you forgot $A.getCallback, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_save_record.htm). Why don't you try that, first?

Comment: After some ugly hacks, I do get it to work, but with minor issues. I created a gist - maybe you can check it out. But the summary is: I have one function in a helper method to create the lead, and another function to load a sales appointment record.
Why can't I, inside the "createLead" function, do something like "this.loadSalesAppointment();" - if I put the entire code of loadSalesAppointment inside the "createLead" function, it works, but that feels very cluttered.. I wrote some comments in "BookingDetailHelper"

https://gist.github.com/erikvlm/aab0ce59a91d1cd218d2b40f6c11e511

Comment: @erikvm based on what you wrote, looks like you can just change `this` to `helper`, since you're already passing the helper as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox - that actually worked. So, if a helper method inside another helper method needs to be called, it's just "helper..." whereas if it's in a controller, it's "this..."?

Comment: @erikvm It's all about context. If you use an arrow function (`(...) => { ... }`), `this` should work just fine in the helper. If you use a full function `function(...) { ... }`, then `this` will get hijacked into something else, so you need a reference to the helper. Without using an arrow function, it would be `var helper = this; ... function(...) { ... }` It might be worth asking a full question if you're still confused.

Comment: I think I understand. I guess it's a JavaScript thing with the whole `this` keyword. 

I think you've answered everything I need, thanks a lot!