# Calling a setCallBack inside another setCallback

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soap-api

I have too function to call, the result of action1 will be feed into function 2:
I have tried to following methods but didnt work:

```
handleSoap: function(component,event,helper) {
    var mastrSoap = component.get("c.EinheitSolar");
    var apiKey = 'NUMBER';
    var marktakteurMastrNummer = 'NUMBER';

    mastrSoap.setParams({apiKey:apiKey,marktakteurMastrNummer:marktakteurMastrNummer,einheitMastrNummer: component.get("v.mastrId")});

    mastrSoap.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        var res = response.getReturnValue();
        /*console.log(res);*/
        var deserializeRes = JSON.parse(res);
        component.set('v.response',deserializeRes);
        var eegNummer = deserializeRes.EegMastrNummer;
        console.log(eegNummer);

        var mastrSoapEeg = component.get("c.AnlageEegSolar")
        mastrSoapEeg.setParams({apiKey:apiKey,marktakteurMastrNummer:marktakteurMastrNummer,eegMastrNummer: eegNummer});
        mastrSoapEeg.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var resEeg = response.getReturnValue();

            component.set('v.responseEeg',JSON.parse(resEeg));

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(mastrSoapEeg);

       });
       $A.enqueueAction(mastrSoap);

    }
```

Any fix?

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to move code execution to the helpers:

**helper**

```
({
    invokeEinheitSolar: function (component) {
        let helper = this;
        var mastrSoap = component.get("c.EinheitSolar");
        var apiKey = 'NUMBER';
        var marktakteurMastrNummer = 'NUMBER';

        mastrSoap.setParams({
            apiKey: apiKey,
            marktakteurMastrNummer: marktakteurMastrNummer,
            einheitMastrNummer: component.get("v.mastrId")
        });

        mastrSoap.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var res = response.getReturnValue();
            /*console.log(res);*/
            var deserializeRes = JSON.parse(res);
            component.set('v.response', deserializeRes);
            var eegNummer = deserializeRes.EegMastrNummer;
            console.log(eegNummer);
            helper.invoAnlageEegSolar(component, apiKey, marktakteurMastrNummer, eegNummer);

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(mastrSoap);
    },

    invoAnlageEegSolar: function (component, apiKey, marktakteurMastrNummer, eegNummer) {
        var mastrSoapEeg = component.get("c.AnlageEegSolar")
        mastrSoapEeg.setParams({
            apiKey: apiKey,
            marktakteurMastrNummer: marktakteurMastrNummer,
            eegMastrNummer: eegNummer
        });
        mastrSoapEeg.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var resEeg = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set('v.responseEeg', JSON.parse(resEeg));

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(mastrSoapEeg);
    }
})
```

and call `invokeEinheitSolar` from the controller

```
handleSoap: function(component,event,helper) {
    helper.invokeEinheitSolar(component);
}
```

---

also to get more flexibility of chaining calls, you can use [Promises in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204487/how-to-make-code-which-uses-lightning-promises-look-more-synchronous)