# Server Lightning calls using promises

Tags: lightning-aura-components, promises

EDIT:

I could not figured out how my code is different from the link you provided and the blog, is that possible to pinpoint what/where i'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to wrap my head around with `promises` and I have multiple `serverside calls` here is what I'm trying to figure out:

1. Only executes the second server call if the `FOUND` is true, for the sake of testing I have hard-coded the boolean value but in the real scenario I will be reading from server side.

Why I'm doing the conditional call?
I don't want to hit the server if the first call returns false.

Here is what I have done so far:

Apex:

```
public class PromiseTestController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String serverSideCall1(String message ){
        return ' From Server serverSideCall1-->' +message ;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String serverSideCall2(String message ){
        return ' From Server serverSideCall2-->' +message ;
    }
     
}
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="PromiseTestController ">
    
    <aura:attribute name="serverSideCall1" type="String"  default="Not started" />
    <aura:attribute name="serverSideCall2" type="String"  default="Not started" />
     <ui:button label="PromiseChaining " press="{!c.promiseChaining}" />
    
     <div>
        {!v.serverSideCall1}
    </div>
   
    <div>
        {!v.serverSideCall2}
    </div> 
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
     
    promiseChaining : function(component, event, helper) {

        var found = false; //TESTING
        var exeAction = component.get("c.serverSideCall1");
        exeAction.setParams( {"message": 'Promise serverSideCall1'});
        helper.serverSideCall(component,exeAction).then(
            function(res) {
                  component.set("v.serverSideCall1" ,res ) ; //RETURN FROM SERVER...serverSideCall1
                if (found) {
                  var exeAction2 = component.get("c.serverSideCall2");
                  exeAction2.setParams( {"message": 'Promise serverSideCall2});
                  helper.serverSideCall(component,exeAction2).then (function (res) {;
                   component.set("v.serverSideCall2" ,res ) ; //RETURN FRO SERVER serverSideCall2
                })
                
            } 
        .catch(
            function(error) {
                component.set("v.status" ,error ) ; 
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    },
    
    
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    serverSideCall : function(component,action) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
            action.setCallback(this, 
                               function(response) {
                                   var state = response.getState();
                                   if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                                       resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                                   } else {
                                       reject(new Error(response.getError()));
                                   }
                               }); 
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        });
    },
  
    
})
```

Comment: Hi Nick! I've actually already covered this in a previous question, and also posted [something on my blog](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2020/03/small-framework-for-server-side-calls.html) you can look at. If all this doesn't help, feel free to let me know, and I'll be more than happy to reopen your question for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox it will be helpful to know what/where i'm doing wrong in order for me to understand and I looked at the link and the blog but could not figured out what i'm doing wrong and it looks like i have the similar  `promise` pattern

Comment: @sfdcfox the link (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204487/how-to-make-code-which-uses-lightning-promises-look-more-synchronous) you provided does not have a full code and it's hard to understand what is going.

Comment: I was already in the process of writing up an answer for you. Hopefully it'll be more clear to you and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Your serverSideCall method looks fine ([just like mine, for example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204487/how-to-make-code-which-uses-lightning-promises-look-more-synchronous)). What you're missing is that you need to "return" the promise in order to continue the chain. The "then" blocks go on the outside in a proper chain (`call().then(doMore).then(doEvenMore)`). If you don't do it this way, the remaining calls will fizzle out. The following code is a modification of your own code. Of course, this won't directly chain (we haven't set `found` to true), but hopefully this demonstrates the solution.

```
({
    properPromiseChaining: function(component, event, helper) {
        var found = false;
        var exeAction = component.get("c.serverSideCall1");
        exeAction.setParams(({message:"Promise serverSideCall1"}));
        // This is the first promise
        helper.serverSideCall(
            component, exeAction
        ).then(
            // Result of first promise
            function(result) {
                component.set("v.serverSideCall1", result);
                if(found) {
                    var exeAction2 = component.get("c.serverSideCall2");
                    exeAction2.setParams({message:"Promise serverSideCall2"});
                    // We need to return the promise in order to chain it
                    return helper.serverSideCall(
                        component, exeAction2
                    );
                }
            }
        ).then(
            // This is the result of the second promise
            function(result) {
                component.set("v.serverSideCall2", result);
            }
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks, I set the `found=true` and I see that it's not executing the last `.then` have you tried?